# InvalidCharacterException not catching characters

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, custom-exceptions

I'm doing an assignment for a class that requires me to throw a RuntimeException if an invalid character is entered by the user. This input will be used to convert an expression that's in post fix-notation to infix. Now, I have my assignment completed, but I can't get the RuntimeException to catch properly. I tried creating an InvalidCharacterException, but that doesn't catch anything either.

What I'm asking is why my method isn't catching characters and throwing an exception
Here are my classes for reference

postfixExpression

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class postfixExpression extends JPanel 
{ 
   private JFrame frame;//The frame
   private JPanel panel;//The panel
   private JLabel enterPostfix;
   private JTextField postfixExpression;
   private JButton construct;
   private JButton blank;
   private JLabel results;
   private JTextField resultsDisplay;





   //Builds the GUI
   public postfixExpression()
   {
       frame=new JFrame("Three Address Generator");
       panel=new JPanel();
       enterPostfix=new JLabel("Enter Postfix Expression");
       postfixExpression=new JTextField("");
       construct=new JButton("Construct Tree");
       blank=new JButton();
       results=new JLabel("Infix Expression");
       resultsDisplay=new JTextField("");







       construct.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               try
               {
                   String expression=postfixExpression.getText();
                   char[] charArray=expression.toCharArray();
                   treeBuilder et=new treeBuilder();
                   Node root=et.buildTree(charArray);
                   resultsDisplay.setText(treeBuilder.inorder(root));
                   root=et.insertRegisters(charArray);
                   et.writeInstructions(root);
               }
               catch(InvalidCharacterException i)
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid character");
               }

           }
       });



           //Adding the parts together
       panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
       panel.add(enterPostfix);
       panel.add(postfixExpression);
       panel.add(construct);
       panel.add(blank);
       panel.add(results);
       panel.add(resultsDisplay);
       frame.add(panel);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setSize(600,300);
       frame.setBackground(Color.red);
       frame.setVisible(true);;





   }           






   //Main method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       postfixExpression myGUI=new postfixExpression();
   }
 }
```

treeBuilder

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class treeBuilder
{

//Checks if the current character is an operator
public  boolean isOperator(char c)
{
    return Character.isDigit(c);
}

//Checks if the current character is an Integer
public boolean isInteger(char c)
{
    int test=Character.getNumericValue(c);
    Integer test2=(Integer)test;

    if(test2 instanceof Integer)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static String inorder(Node t)
{
    if(t!=null)
    {
        return "("+inorder(t.getLeft())+t.getValue()+" "+inorder(t.getRight())+")";
    }
    return "";
}

public Node buildTree(char postFix[]) throws RuntimeException
{
    Stack<Node> nodeStack=new Stack<Node>();
    Node tree=null;
    Node t1=null;
    Node t2=null;

    for(int i=0;i<postFix.length;i++)
    {
        if(!isOperator(postFix[i])&&!isInteger(postFix[i]))
        {
            throw new InvalidCharacterException(postFix[i]);

        }
        if(!isOperator(postFix[i]))
        {
            tree=new Node(postFix[i]);
            nodeStack.push(tree);
        }
        else if(isOperator(postFix[i]))
        {
            tree= new Node(postFix[i]);
            t1=nodeStack.pop();
            t2=nodeStack.pop();
            tree.setRight(t1);
            tree.setLeft(t2);
            nodeStack.push(tree);
        }
        else if(!isOperator(postFix[i])&& !isInteger(postFix[i]))
        {
            throw new InvalidCharacterException(postFix[i]);
        }


    }
    tree=nodeStack.pop();
    return tree;
}


public Node insertRegisters(char[] postFix)
{
    Stack<Node> nodeStack=new Stack<Node>();
    Node tree=null;
    Node t1=null;
    Node t2=null;
    int registerCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<postFix.length;i++)
    {
        if(!isOperator(postFix[i]))
        {
            tree=new Node(postFix[i]);
            nodeStack.push(tree);
        }
        else if(isOperator(postFix[i]))
        {
            tree = new Node(postFix[i], "R" + registerCount++);
            t1 = nodeStack.pop();
            t2 = nodeStack.pop();
            tree.setRight(t1);
            tree.setLeft(t2);
            nodeStack.push(tree);
        }

    }
    return tree;
}


public String writeInstructionsHelper(Node root)
{
    String str="";
    if(root != null)
    {
        if(root.getLeft()!=null && root.getLeft().getRegister() !=null)
        {
            str += writeInstructionsHelper(root.getLeft());
        }
        if(root.getRight()!=null && root.getRight().getRegister() !=null)
        {
            str += writeInstructionsHelper(root.getRight());
        }

        String instructions=null;
        if(root.getValue()=='+')
        {
            instructions="Add";
        }
        else if(root.getValue()=='-')
        {
            instructions="Sub";
        }
        else if(root.getValue()=='*')
        {
            instructions="Mul";
        }
        else if(root.getValue()=='/')
        {
            instructions="Div";
        }

        if(root.getRegister()==null)
        {
            str+=root.getValue();
        }
        else
        {
            str += instructions + " ";
            str += root.getRegisterOrValue() + " ";
            str += root.getLeft().getRegisterOrValue() + " ";
            str += root.getRight().getRegisterOrValue();
        }
    }
    str+="\r\n";
    return str;
}

public void writeInstructions(Node root)
{
    String file="myFile.txt";
    try
    {
        String instructions = writeInstructionsHelper(root);
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(file);
        outputStream.println(instructions);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}   
}
```

InvalidCharacterException

```
public class InvalidCharacterException extends RuntimeException
{
private char c;

public InvalidCharacterException(char c)
{
    this.c=c;
}

public char getCharacter()
{
    return c;
}
}
```

Node class

```
public class Node
{
private char value;
private String register;
private Node left;
private Node right;

public Node(char value)
{
    this.value=value;
    left=null;
    right=null;
    register=null;
}
public Node(char value, String register)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.register = register;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}
public char getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(char value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getRegister() {
    return register;
}

public void setRegister(String register) {
    this.register = register;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(Node left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(Node right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public String getRegisterOrValue()
{
    if (register == null)
    {
        return "" + value; // must convert to string
    }
    else
    {
        return register;
    }
}



public String toStringHelper(int indents) {
    String str = "";

    str += "value: " + value + "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < indents; i++) {
        str += "\t";
    }
    if (left == null)
        str += "LEFT: null\n";
    else
        str += "LEFT: " + left.toStringHelper(indents + 1) + "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < indents; i++) {
        str += "\t";
    }
    if (right == null)
        str += "RIGHT: null\n";
    else
        str += "RIGHT: " + right.toStringHelper(indents + 1) + "\n";

    return str;
}



}
```

Comment: why dont you use Exeception to catch it as a last resort or do you explicitly have to use the ones you mentioned about?

Comment: The assignment says I have to throw a RuntimeException in the main class, which is the one that defines the GUI I believe

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: It’s a lot of code (and as discussed with my answer, not complete). Another time, see if you can [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isInteger` method is always returning true. So you never detect any invalid characters and hence never throw your exception.

How can that be? For most invalid characters, `Character.getNumericValue(c)` will return -1. You convert this number into an `Integer` instance and then test whether it is an `Integer`. It is. It’s even declared an integer, so the test could never fail. So your method returns `true`. Back in your `buildTree` method, the the `if` condition will be false and your `throw` statement not reached.

My immediate idea for a fix would be in the `isInteger` method to return `false` if you get a negative result from `Character.getNumericValue(c)`. You may want to read the documentation of that method once more before you make a final decision.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the characters a-z and A-Z all have numerical values, so they wouldn't return as -1

Comment: True. Maybe you should rather use `Character.isDigit()` instead? @WILLO567

Comment: I just tried using the Character.isDigit(), and it's still not catching any letters and throwing the exception. It does it when there's an operator, but only if the operator leads the expression. For reference, my next else if statement is :    else if(!isOperator(postFix[i])&& !isInteger(postFix[i])

Comment: I changed the body of `isInteger()` to just `return Character.isDigit(c);`. Ran the program (only with the `Node` class stubbed). Entered `45%`. Clicked Construct Tree. Got the message Invalid character. Same with `45a`, `a` alone and `a+`. You may want to edit your question and explain precisely what you are trying.

Comment: I changed the method as you said, but I got the same result as I did last time. I know this will be a dumb question, but what do you mean when you had the Node class stubbed?

Comment: Nevermind, I just misplaced some code. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to answer: You had not provided you `Node` class, so I had my Eclipse generate one for me and most of the methods. I guessed a few return types and entered them manually. This was then the `Node` class I was using. A method stub is a substitute for the real method, see for example [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub).